# jquery select option which was created using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i am trying to select an option from select which i think was created using knockoutjs(but i am not sure)

```
<select class="styled" data-bind="options: Locations, optionsText: 'Name', value: DesiredLocat…ion: SelectLocationText(), event: { change: UpdateLocation }">

<option value="">

    Select location

</option>
<option value="">

    Some location

</option>
<option value="">

    Some location2

</option>

</select>
```

the whole thing is bundled in a frame, i've googled how to make jquery work in frame and now i am using it like this

```
var frameDocument= $("frame[name='mainFrame']", top.document)[0].contentDocument;
```

i tried to do it like this:

```
$(frameDocument).find('.styled').val('Some location').change();
```

and like this:

```
$(frameDocument).find('.styled').children().each(function(){
     if ($(this).text()=='Some location'){
        $(this).click();
         return false;
      }
})
```

can anyone please help me on how to select the option i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to not using `jquery` since you are using `knokout.js` .

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/82/

HTML:

```
<select class="styled" data-bind="options: Locations, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',value: selectedLocation">
```

JS:

```
function MainViewModel() {
  var self = this ;
  self.Locations = ko.observableArray([{Name:"Location 1" , Id : 1 },{Name:"Location 2" , Id : 2 },{Name:"Location 3" , Id : 3 }]);
  self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();
  self.selectedLocation.subscribe(function(newValue){
    console.log(newValue);
  })
}

ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
```

Comment: and how should i select the option using knockout?

Comment: the thing is that i am not an owner of the website, i am writing a crawler for it and i need to select an option. In chrome when i enter `ko` in developer console it gives me the object, however, in firefox it doesn't. i believe it has something to do with frames. As i said the whole thing is bundled in a frame like this: `<frameset id='main'><frame>page that i want to crawl is here</frame></frameset>`

Comment: you need to find out which view model it belongs to also if there is any parent view model and then update the knockout observable value. For example : `MainVM.SubVM().selectedLocation(3);`

Comment: but is it possible to select only with jquery? without knockoutjs

Comment: If it's a knockout select binding it has to be done by using knockout otherwise nothing gets changed or updated in `knockout` model and you won't see any changes on view